# How to manage state between android app and ASP.net Web API?

Tags: android, c#-4.0, session-cookies, session-state

We have android app through which retailer can recharge customers mobile. So we need to authorize every recharge request.

To send recharge request retailer needs to hit api with recharge related information and userid and userkey. As below

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public IHttpActionResult Prepaid(int pUserID = -1, string pKey = "", string pCustomerNo = "", decimal pAmount = 1, int pServiceProviderId = -1, int pDeviceTypeId = -1)
```

We authenticate user for every api hit comparing userkey(encrypeted password) with password stored in db

This makes too many db calls and our server gets slow

Its b2b app and retailer perform different kind action like transaction history, credit request, book complaint other than just recharge

How to maintain state after user login to Android app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, REST by design is stateless. By adding session (or anything else of that kind) you are making it stateful and defeating any purpose of having a RESTful API.

To achieve authentication and authorization I have used following method:

While user post request from android, user send his userid and password in http authentication header and at server side we check password and if user is authorized the we process user request.

No need to maintain any state between android and web api as api are stateless.

Comment: What about if I don't want to send the password everytime?

Answer (score 0):

If the userkey is a unique identification for every user, or for every one unique mobile number, then i think that it is just better that you verify the mobile number that the user is using to make the recharge by sending an OTP. The user can then send that OTP back for authentication.
But do this only at the time of login, and then store your unique user key that you have generated in a [Shared preference](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) storage.

Comment: Its b2b app not b2c. and retailer perform different kind action like transaction history, credit request, book complaint other than just recharge

Comment: You do not need to authenticate the user everytime for a recharge or anything else. Just authenticate the user on login and store your "user_key" in shared preferences for further use.